# capturing occurrences and finding its count in a list

Tags: python, list, design-patterns

I have a situation where a list of last occurrences is available.
Say the list is.
`['user', 'user', 'sys', 'sys', 'user', 'user', 'sys', 'user']`
So the ask is if a user has occurred how many times did it occur consecutively?
if there is a change in element say 'sys' instead of 'user' the count should start fresh.
The output I am looking for is
`[('user', 2), ('sys', 2), ('user', 2), ('sys', 1), ('user', 1)]`
this would help me identify the pattern the user and system is following.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['user', 'user', 'sys', 'sys', 'user', 'user', 'sys', 'user']

out = [(value, sum(1 for _ in group)) for value, group in groupby(lst)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('user', 2), ('sys', 2), ('user', 2), ('sys', 1), ('user', 1)]
```

Comment: Best answer, from stdlib! Why `sum(1 for _ in group)` instead of `len(list(group))`?

Comment: @NicWolff `len(list(group))` will first create a `list`, so depending on the size of the group it could take too much memory. With `sum(1 for _ in group)` the memory usage is constant (we just iterate over the group).

Answer (score 0):

You could install the `more-itertools` package and use its `run_length.encode` function:

```
In [1]: from more_itertools import run_length

In [2]: list(run_length.encode(['user', 'user', 'sys', 'sys', 'user', 'user', 'sys', 'user']))
Out[2]: [('user', 2), ('sys', 2), ('user', 2), ('sys', 1), ('user', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list and count the values using the stack phenomenon without any additional library.
Below is the logic:

```
l = ['user', 'user', 'sys', 'sys', 'user', 'user', 'sys', 'user']

f = []
x = [l[0], 0]

for i in l:
    if i == x[0]:
        x[1] += 1
    else:
        f.append(tuple(x))
        # Resetting the value
        x = [i, 1]

# Adding the last iteration value
f.append(tuple(x))

print(f)
```

where,
x = temporary list which keeps a track of count of topmost value.
Initially, I have started with zero as I am looping first value again.

Output: f -> `[('user', 2), ('sys', 2), ('user', 2), ('sys', 1), ('user', 1)]`